# How do I build an OS X Java Application Bundle in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I'm trying to build a Java application for the mac in IntelliJ IDEA. The Apple Developer docs say I need to make a [Java Application Bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001885-208447-TPXREF120) in order to support things like dock icons, application names etc, but I'm not sure how to set up a build configuration to do all this from within IntelliJ. Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: Does the app. have a GUI?  Reports suggest that some of the abilities that [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) brings to a launch (splash screens, menu items, desktop shortcuts, application title/name) also work on OS X.  ( And JWS also works on Windows & *nix ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support creating such bundles. You can use Ant or some external tool to automate this process.

Comment: Advanced Installer now has a support for IntelliJ IDEA projects, very easy to use, with support for Windows and MacOS : http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/IntelliJ-IDEA-import.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I dit it (MacOS 10.10 + IntelliJ IDEA 15 + JDK 1.8):

1. Download Oracle [Java Application Bundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler/downloads) and place copy it into **/lib** directory of your project.
2. *File* → *Project Structure* → *Artifacts* → *Add (+)* → *JAR* → *From modules With Dependecies...* → Choose Main class → *OK*.
3. *Build* → *Build Artifacts...* → Generate **jar** in /out/artifacts/...
4. Create **build.xml** at your project's root:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project name="Test" default="bundle-test" basedir=".">
       <taskdef name="bundleapp" 
           classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask" 
           classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0.jar" />    
       <target name="bundle-test">
           <bundleapp outputdirectory="out"
               name="Test"
               displayname="Test"
               identifier="Test"
               mainclassname="Main">
               <classpath file="out/artifacts/test_jar/test.jar" />
           </bundleapp>
       </target>
   </project>
   ```
5. At the Ant Build panel (*View* → *Tool Windows* → *Ant Build*) click *Add (+)* and chose your **build.xml** and press *Run* button.
6. Find your app in **/out** directory of your project.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of Oracle Java7's documentation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html#bundle

Comment: Please try to summarize at least the general gist of the content you link to. Once the link goes dead, your answer will be rendered virtually useless.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a maven plugin and package it as a *.app for OS X. I use this plugin and it seems to be the one which has the latest support. You can refer to this repository for more information https://github.com/federkasten/appbundle-maven-plugin

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>sh.tak.appbundler</groupId>
          <artifactId>appbundle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
```

You can specify the icon, main class and name. On the other hand, an extension for Apple might also help to customize your application.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.apple</groupId>
        <artifactId>AppleJavaExtensions</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Besides this maven solution, Oracle offers a Java Application Bundler which supports other Java runtime (including Java 7, 8 and more). Here is a fork of the offcial bundler, which has more features. https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's not quite the answer you hoped for, but I think ide-builds are good during development, but there should always be a platform (ide, os etc.) independent way to make releases. I prefer [ant](http://ant.apache.org/), which can be perfectly integrated with Idea. Ant itself - as far as I know - does not support mac os application bundles, but here's [one example](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/) of an extension I found on the internet.