# Java Mac App fails to start when bundled with appbundler

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make a standalone Mac App with the appbundler and IntelliJ. I set up my a build.xml (with this tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35698338/2096060) everything compiles without problems. However, when I want to start the MyApp.app it pops up in the dock but closes immediately. When I try to run it with:

`open MyApp.app`

I get the following message:

`LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file ..../MyApp.app.`

It is possible to run the JAR in `MyApp.app/Contents/Java/my_app.jar` with:

`java -jar my_app.jar`

`MyApp.app/Contents/Info.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>English</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>JavaAppLauncher</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>icon_512x512.png</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>de.myapp</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>MyApp</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>MyApp</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
<string></string>
<key>JVMMainClassName</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>JVMOptions</key>
<array>
</array>
<key>JVMArguments</key>
<array>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My stack is:

- Mac OS X 10.11.6
- Java 1.8.0_77
- IntelliJ 2016.1.4

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Post your app/Contents/Info.plist please, maybe there is a wrong java definition

Comment: I added the Info.plist to my post.